# Erasing indices of std::vector inside a for loop based on vector size

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I've created a function to filter out the elements I don't like in a std::vector, in this case a vector of opencv contours.  The code below looks like it would work, however it does not and I suspect it is because the indices are changed whenever I erase the indices, however I continue to the next i value iteration.

```
void FilterContours( std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {

        //Remove contours smaller than 5 from vector - example
        if ( contours[i].size() < 5 ) {
            contours.erase(contours.begin() + i);
            continue;
        }

        //Other filtering...
    }
    return;
}
```

So the question is, would this work as intended (I don't think it does), and if not, how do I make it work as intended?  Should I add a i -= 1 after the erase to maintain the correct index position?

Comment: Don't erase this way.  Just use the erase / remove_if idiom.

Comment: ^^ but if you thought adding `i -= 1` more simply `--i` in your if would work, why didn't you just try that? Also, while it's not an issue here, remember that if you loop based on a fixed iterator like `std::vector::end`, and you modify the size of the vector without updating the end iterator, it will result in UB.

Comment: Some advice -- if you find yourself writing loops that seem as if they've been written a thousand times before by someone else, chances are is that there is an STL algorithm or set of algorithm functions that do the job.  In your case, erasing items from a sequence container is one of those things that has been dome millions of times before, thus we have algorithms that cover this scenario (std::remove_if)

Comment: Excellent responses guys, the erase-remove idiom was my final solution and had a pretty significant difference in performance.  @Paul-- You're right, I figured there was something in the STL algorithm but I just had trouble nailing down the one I needed and knew I'd get a pretty straight response here quick, and sure enough I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you `erase()` an element from a container, its `size()` decrements, and the indexes of the remaining elements are decremented as well.  But you are incrementing your loop counter unconditionally, so every time you erase an element, you *skip* the next element that had followed it!

Also, you are passing your `vector` by-value, so you are operating on a *copy* of the `vector`, and the caller will not see any changes in the original `vector`.

The correct approach would be to either:

1. increment your index variable inside of the loop body only when an element is NOT erased.  Leave the variable as-is when you DO erase an element:

   ```
   void FilterContours( std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> &contours )
   {
       int i = 0;
       while ( i < contours.size() ) {
           if ( contours[i].size() < 5 ) {
               contours.erase(contours.begin() + i);
               continue;
           }

           //Other filtering...

           ++i;
       }
   }
   ```
2. use iterators instead of indexes:

   ```
   void FilterContours( std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> &contours )
   {
       auto it = contours.begin();
       while ( it != contours.end() ) {
           if ( it->size() < 5 ) {
               it = contours.erase(it);
               continue;
           }

           //Other filtering...

           ++it;
       }
   }
   ```
3. use the [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) idiom:

   ```
   void FilterContours( std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> &contours )
   {
       contours.erase(
           std:::remove_if(
               contours.begin(),
               contours.end(),
               [](const std::vector<cv::Point> &v)
               {
                   if (v.size() < 5) return true; 
                   //Other filtering...
                   return false;
               }
           ),
           contours.end()
       );
   }
   ```

Comment: You might be missing a the second argument of `erase` in the second code block.

Comment: I tried a few of the solutions and the erase-remove idiom provided the best performance.  Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Use the erase-remove idiom:

```
contours.erase(
  std::remove_if(contours.begin(), contours.end(), [](const std::vector<cv::Point>& v){
    return v.size() < 5;
  }),
  contours.end()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you iterate for removing, it is always better to iterate **backwards**:

```
for ( int i = contours.size()-1; i >=0; --i)
```

This will work but it results in slow code, because at each removal, the elements behind the removal will be copied/shifted back. For this reason, it is better, faster and more readable to use the dedicated idioms provided by the standard algorithm library, which are usually very optimized. In this case you have the `erase/remove_if` combination:

```
contours.erase(std::remove_if(contours.begin(), contours.end(), [](const auto& elem) { return elem.size() < 5; }), contours.end() );
```

A big advantage here is that `std::remove_if()` acts in a smarter way than the intuitive loop: it first "marks" the elements to remove, and then it compacts the remaining elements together. This process is O(N), while the (intuitive) loop is O(N^2), a huge difference for big vectors.

p.s.: the signature of your `FilterContours` function to take the vector by reference:

```
void FilterContours( std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>& contours ) // <-- by reference
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `FilterContours` should take a reference, otherwise it won't have any impact on the caller.

```
void FilterContours(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>& contours)
{
    for (auto it = contours.begin(); it != contours.end(); )
    {
        if (it->size() < 5)
            it = contours.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
```

*Edit:*
If you want to do it in the reverse order you could do:

```
void FilterContours_reverse(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>& contours)
{
    for (auto it = contours.rbegin(); it != contours.rend(); )
    {
        if (it->size() < 5)
            contours.erase(std::next(it++).base());
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
```